# how to loop through a Json responce

Tags: php, json

I have web page which get Json responce like this

```
{
   'hotel_1page':[
      {
         'id':'10',
         'name':'fsf',
         'telephone':'233333'
      },
      {
         'id':'11',
         'name':'setttttt',
         'telephone':'213123123'
      },
      {
         'id':'12',
         'name':'fsdfsdf',
         'telephone':'122212121'
      },
      {
         'id':'13',
         'name':'xxcvcxv',
         'telephone':'2147483647'
      },
      {
         'id':'14',
         'name':'dssdfg',
         'telephone':'2147483647'
      },
      {
         'id':'15',
         'name':'dfsdfsdf',
         'telephone':'21312321'
      },
      {
         'id':'16',
         'name':'fx_test_nw1',
         'telephone':'23232323'
      },
      {
         'id':'17',
         'name':'fx_test_nw2',
         'telephone':'31313131'
      }
   ]
}
```

and i want to loop through this data and get this data to array and display as html how can i achieve this

this is where i get get json responce,and  when i var_dump json encoded variable it says null,where `$json` variable shows the json responce,

```
$json = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/hotel_list.php'); 

var_dump($json);  
$array = json_decode($json, true);
var_dump($array);
```

Comment: http://php.net/foreach

Comment: thanks but i know it's foreach loop but how i loop through it i try like foreach($array->response->hotel_1page as $hotels) but did't work...

Comment: I think that the single quotes need to be double quotes instead. I copied your json string to a validator after replacing the quotes and then it was valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
$json = '{ "hotel_1page": [ { "id": "10", "name": "fsf", "telephone": "233333" }, { "id": "11", "name": "setttttt", "telephone": "213123123" }, { "id": "12", "name": "fsdfsdf", "telephone": "122212121" }, { "id": "13", "name": "xxcvcxv", "telephone": "2147483647" }, { "id": "14", "name": "dssdfg", "telephone": "2147483647" }, { "id": "15", "name": "dfsdfsdf", "telephone": "21312321" }, { "id": "16", "name": "fx_test_nw1", "telephone": "23232323" }, { "id": "17", "name": "fx_test_nw2", "telephone": "31313131" } ] }';

echo '<pre>';
var_dump(json_decode($json, true));
echo '</pre>';
```

I replaced all single quotes with double quotes, that did the trick.
I used single quotes before which caused json_decode to return null

[Edit for usage]

To use the data, you could use something like this:

```
 $obj = json_decode($json, true);

 foreach($obj as $row)
 {
     foreach($row as $key => $item)
     {
         // $item['id']
         // $item['name']
         // $item['telephone']
     }
 }
```

I'm using a nested foreach() because the id, name and telephone are an array within the hotel_page1 array

Comment: yap it's working but my foreach loop nw has a problem can  pls show how to loop through this..,

Answer (score 2):

The json that you are trying to parse is invalid. Change the single quotes to double quotes and you should be able to parse it to an array.

The JSON [documentation](http://www.json.org/) says

> A value can be a string in double quotes, or a number, or true or false or null, or an object or an array. These structures can be nested.